# ftplib retrlines error_proto

Tags: python, ftp, centos

i have pyftpdlib 0.7.0 on my Centos Server and i use ftplib on my client
when i try run this commands i get this error

client os : windows 7
python V : 2.7
server os : CentOs

my cod :

```
from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
ftp.login(user='xxx', passwd='xxx' )
ls = []
ftp.retrlines('RETR 2.jpg', callback =ls.append)
print ls
```

and error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\py\ftp test\ftpTest.py", line 7, in <module>
    ftp.retrlines('RETR 2.jpg', callback =ls.append)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 422, in retrlines
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 361, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 330, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 244, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 220, in getresp
    raise error_proto, resp
error_proto:
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I have a similar issue.  http://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps, but this is the way I've written my file retrieve lines:

```
        gfile = open(filename, 'wb')
        ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s' % filename, gfile.write)
        gfile.close()
```

I had an issue like this a while but it was not exactly the same as yours, the fix for me was to change the format on my ftp.retr line, the RETR needed to be in "" by itself and the filename seperate. yours is using a list obviously but this is just how i had it in my program.